# MVC Telerik Grid Page Navigation Failing

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid, uinavigationitem

I've tried,

```
.Pageable(p => p.Enabled(true).PageSize(20))
.Pageable(p => p.Enabled(true)
            .PageSize(20)
            .PageTo(10))
.Pageable()
```

And so far what I've noticed is I can navigate left but all the page navigations to go right just show up as the web address/link to the page I'm on and it's displaying rather than say page 11 or 2.

Clicking on the page numbers also does nothing.
With using firebug it just shows the right arrows as not having a href and nothing for the page numbers.

Being made in VS10,MVC2,C#, AJAX binding

Any idea what could be causing this or what/where the code that should be handling this is in telerik.grid.min.js or if it's in common/filtering(other than textbox those are the only telerik .js running for it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to update my jquery.validate.min.js